# How can I export all emails between myself and another person from Gmail, i.e., to send to a third party as a readable file?

Tags: gmail, export

I have had a large number of conversations about a project with another person using Gmail, and Gmail has effectively served to document the development process.

I would like to share these conversation with another colleague so that they can be reviewed and summarized.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's all within a conversation, just [forward it all](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=6586).

If you've got too many spread conversations, your best bet might be giving them all a label and using your favorite [IMAP Client](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/topic.py?topic=12806) to forward them. By labeling them you van easily select the messages that will be in an IMAP folder on your application.

There's still no way to do it within gmail, and it's even [pre-listed as a suggestion](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/static.py?page=suggestions.cs). Go there and cast your vote for it!

Comment: "(...) you *van* easily (...)" - and I'm no german.